# React Typescript generic props stop working when adding additional prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, typescript-generics

I have a React component that takes an array of data (T) and provides a number of functions to specify what properties in the object to display in various locations etc.

It all worked perfectly until I decided to add a new prop to the component that was also typed using the generic type, now everything is typed to either `object` or `never`

It's like there is a limit to how many properties I can use generic typing in, am I missing something?

This works:

```
type BarChartProps<T> = {
    data: T[];
    bars: DataKey<T>[];
    yAxis: AxisProps<T>;
    height: number;
};
```

This does not work:

```
type BarChartProps<T> = {
    data: T[];
    bars: DataKey<T>[];
    yAxis: AxisProps<T>;
    xAxis: AxisProps<T>;
    height: number;
};
```

**Update:**

Here are the types I am using inside BarChartProps:

```
type Keys<T> = keyof T & string;

type DataKey<T> = {
    key: Keys<T>;
    label: string;
    color: string;
};

type AxisProps<T> = {
    key: Keys<T>;
    ticks?: (string | number)[];
    tickCount?: number;
    tickFormatter?: (val: number) => string;
};
```

And here is the usage:

```
<Chart.BarChart
    data={chartData}
    height={258}
    yAxis={{ key: "name" }}
    bars={[
        {
            key: "present",
            label: "Present",
            color: "#efb15d",
        },
        {
            key: "absent",
            label: "Absent",
            color: "#efb15d",
        },
    ]}
/>
```

The `key` field in `yAxis` is typed correctly and will only let me send in a string that matches a key from the objects sent in through the data array, however after adding `xAxis` I get errors that the value is not assignable to `never`

**Update**
Today when I opened the project it just worked, haven't changed a thing

Comment: What "doesn't work"? How is it notworking?

Comment: Before I added the xAxis prop, yAxis would be typed correctly using the type from the data array, after I added xAxis the data is typed as "object"

Comment: Can you show the usage?

Comment: I have updated the question with some more details, thanks